# How call a function that is stored on a different folder and file?

Tags: php, function, session

I am completely new on PHP, I crated two functions stored on a different folder and file. I would like to know how to call these functions on any file. Here my files.

**\functions\funciones.php file**

```
    <?php 
    //Comprueba si existe una sesión activa, si no redirecciona al index.php
    function ComprobarSesion () {
        if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
    // Funcion conexión a la DB. Validar si tambien se peude meter en una funcion. 
    function Conexion_DB(){
        try {
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=login','root','');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**\index.php file**

```
    <?php session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['USUARIO'])) {
        header('Location: contenido.php');
    }   else {
        header('Location: registro.php');
    }
    ?>
```

As you can see in the "index.php" file, I have the code that I want to remove and put the function... but I don't know how to replace it.

Comment: Which function are you trying to call?

Comment: Did you start the session in the first file? That's unclear since it doesn't appear that you have.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes.

Comment: @softwareisfun both.

Answer (score 1):

You could use require_once.

Put this at the top of your index-file

```
<?php 
require_once('/absolute/path/to/your/file.php');
```

Replace the path and desired file.

Then you can call the function in your index.php like this

```
ComprobarSesion();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I will try in this moment.

Comment: Make sure the dependencies are require first then you can use it. PHP is a scripting language so like all scripting languages, you need to let the page be aware of functions by declaring it

Comment: This error happened: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function require_one() in D:\xampp\htdocs\Login_registro\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: You have a typo @user9613821. `required_once`. You have required_one.

Comment: Hi @AjAX. but in the documentation said... [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php). I used according the doc but now my website is completely blank. I'm testing and reading :)